# Maintaining parallel work branches with Git

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch, git-merge

The Git repository I'm working on has two main branches `alpha` and `beta`, both similar and both being actively worked on. When I'm working on a feature, it needs to be committed into both branches. Despite the contents of the branches being almost identical, there is no common ancestor of both `alpha` and `beta`. So far, that's all mandated by my company; there's not a lot I can do about that.

I'm interested in how I can replicate actions I take on a feature branch off one of these branches to a feature branch on the other.

### Specifics

Currently, my workflow is to work on a feature branch `featA` off `alpha`, and regularly cherry-pick commits from `featA` onto a separate feature branch `featB` off `beta`. This results in a commit tree that looks something like the below:

```
A---B---C---E---F (featA)
         \
          D (alpha)

A'--B'--C'--E' (featB)
         \
          D' (beta)
```

At this point, I'd be looking at checking out `featB` and cherry-picking commit `F` onto that branch.

This process generally works okay, but is fairly labour intensive: anything I do on one branch needs to be repeated on the other. Forgetting to do that can produce inconsistencies leading to bugs, and since there is no recorded correlation between (for example) commits `B` and `B'`, tracking down such bugs is non-trivial.

Because there is no common parent commit, and we occasionally make commits to one of `alpha` or `beta` that shouldn't be replicated, I don't think I can use `git merge` to pull commits on one branch to the other.

Is there some workflow improvement or automation I can do to replicate actions on `featA` to some other branch `featB`?

Comment: Why is your company mandating the use of forked long-term branches? It  will generate an awful lot of work and trouble, particularly if they ever need to be brought back in line. Obviously you have no control over it. Mostly just curious because it's a troubled workflow

Comment: @Christopher: the branches are active development branches for different customers. There's a lot of commonality, but some differences, and this was the best scheme anyone came up with when the situation first arose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git cherry-pick` to replicate a commit into the other branch.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but it still requires me to remember to cherry-pick every time, and other operations (eg merges, rebases) similarly need to be replicated.

Comment: You can use ``git format-patch`` if you want to apply series of commits somewhere, but still you will have to type at least 2 commands manually - format patch and apply it.